# Inserting a record in coulmn name "domain" in access

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a record in a column named as "**domain**" in MS Access db from excel using VBA. But it gives an error(Automation error) but with the same code if i change the column name as **domai** or **do** it works fine.

The code is simple insert statement

code:

```
'Insert into tblnm(domain) values('anything')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved words need to be enclosed in `[]`

```
insert into tblnm([domain]) values('anything')
```

http://www.msoffice.us/Access/Access20010Reserved_Words_Special_Characters.htm